# Optimum way of self replication?

Tags: self-learning, exponentiation

Asume you can build a self replicating machine called X. X can perform two functions, further build another machine X in 24 hours or generate a product Y, also in 24 hours. In a 30 day, calculate the maximum number of product Y, given infinite resources? What is the strategy and maths involved?

The question arises because of watching a video on use of Von Neuman technology to terraform planets. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell us what are your thought on this? I've thought of a way of building way over 100 million copies of $Y$, but I would like to see your attempt first! :)

Comment: @Ertxiem Spoiler: I am a medical student and my maths is barely high school level. I tried to work it out the old trial and error way but midway I realized that the maths involved diverges dramatically beyond what can be reasonabally worked with pen/paper and so I realised that there was probably a formula or graph involved that I can run on my computer. I have point blank no idea otherwise.

Comment: Hint: try to solve simpler problems. Instead of $30$ days, start by thinking what would be possible in **$3$** days (or $2$ days, or $1$ day). Then try to see a pattern, that is what Maths is all about -- if you see a pattern, can you formalize it in an elegant way and then generalize it. Regarding medicine, or any other science, I believe that having this type of skill can be useful.

Comment: @Erxiem Fair eough but can you tell me about the 100 million approach you took?

Comment: Yes I can, but I will only do it after you solve the $1$, $2$ and $3$ days problems. :) Those are not hard.

Comment: @Erxiem I get that the answer is 1 for 1 day, 2 for 2 day and 4 for 3 days. The answer will probably be 2^(d-1) where d is the number of days, giving an answer of 536,870,912 with 30 being number of days but that will be if the machines do nothing but replicate and produce only on last day or last two days. I wonder if there was a rigrous mathematical proof for such. Thanks for the excercise though.

Comment: Well done! As for the proof: let's say that at day $t$ before the last $0 < n \leq 2^{t-1}$ machines build $Y$ instead of a copy. In that case, you'll end up with $(2^{t} - n) \times 2^{d-t-1} + n = 2^{d-1} - (2^{d-t-1}-1)n < 2^{d-1}$ copies of $Y$.

Comment: @Ertxiem Man you are smart. Thanks I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted an answer with the same information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly found out, the solution is to replicate the $X$ machines until the last day and then produce
$$
2^{d-1}
$$
copies of machine $Y$.

Regarding the proof, I'll do a sketch.

Let's consider a deviation from the above strategy.
Say that at day $t$ before the last $0 < n \leq 2^{t-1}$ machines build $Y$ instead of a copy.
In that case, you'll end up with 
$$
(2^{t} - n) \times 2^{d-t-1} + n = 2^{d-1} - (2^{d-t-1}-1)n < 2^{d-1}
$$ copies of $Y$.
By analogy we could consider 2,3,4,... deviations from this strategy and we would always get less copies of $Y$ in the end.